# How to hide a blue cursor in a textfield and a keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get an empty textfield when my ViewController Appears. I tried this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    linkField.placeholder = "test"
    linkField.text = ""
}
```

But when it appears the keyboard pops up and a blue cursor blinks in a textField.
How can I get rid of those ?

**EDIT:**

I think I didn't explain my question correctly. I don't need to get an empty cursor, I just need to hide it and the keyboard until user touches the textfield to input something.

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: Look at the edited answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The textfield cursor color is based on the default tint color. In your case it's blue. I would change the tint color to clear color.

```
linkField.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

For the edited question, if you just want to dismiss the keyboard then

```
linkField.resignFirstResponder()
```

will dismiss the keyboard and when you want focus again use

```
linkField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Where did you resign the text field, viewDidAppear?

Comment: i'm sorry, first time i added it to viewWillAppear, but now i changed to ViewDidAppear and it works! Thank you <3

Answer (score 2):

Create subclass of `UITextField` and override `caretRectForPosition`

```
import UIKit

class RemoveBlinkCursor: UITextField {
    override init(frame:CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func caretRectForPosition(position: UITextPosition!) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectZero
    }
}
```

[image]

After your edit answer changed :

For show and hide keyboard and focus you can use resign and become first responders as said by Vig.

Hope this will help to others for removing blinking bar.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
self.textField.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It makes the cursor invisible, but it should be visible when the user touches the text field and the keyboard still pops up.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 Xcode 8**

Calling `view.endEditing(true)` has always worked for me